# How to get all possible array attributions of numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

- Python: get all possible array attributions of nd arrays. Use `itertools.product`?

  - If so, how?
- In Python, I have two n dimensions numpy arrays `A` and `B` (`B` is a zero array).
- Such way `A.shape[i]<=B.shape[i]`, for any i between `0` and `n`.
  I want to create a for loop in such way every iteration I attribute `A` to a different subset of `B`, in such way every possible position in occupied until the end of the for loop.

for instance, with `A = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])` and `B = np.zeros((3,4))`, I would get these(one of these for each iteration):

```
1 1 1 0       0 1 1 1       0 0 0 0      0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0       0 1 1 1       1 1 1 0      0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0       0 0 0 0       1 1 1 0      0 1 1 1
```

For a fixed `n` dimension it is trivial, just use nested for loops for each dimension.
However, I want it for a generic `n` dimensions.

My approach was to use the `itertools.product` to get all combinations of indexes.
In the above example, `product([0,1],[0,1])`, would iterate over `(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)`, and I would have my indexes.
However, I don't know how to pass the values of the parameters to product function for a generic `n`.
Any idea? There are better ways of doing so?

Comment: "However, I don't know how to pass the values of the parameters to product function for a generic `n`." Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters help?

Answer (score 2):

itertools product should work.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

A = np.ones((2,3))
B = np.zeros((3,4))

r_rng = range(B.shape[0]-A.shape[0]+1)
c_rng = range(B.shape[1]-A.shape[1]+1)

for i,j in product(r_rng, c_rng):
    C = B.copy()
    C[i:i+A.shape[0],j:j+A.shape[1]]=A
    print(C,'\n')
```

Output:

```
[[1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]

[[0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0.]]

[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 0.]]

[[0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

Comment: This example is for a 2D array, in a nD, we would have to use n 'range(B.shape[i]-A.shape[i]+1)' expressions as params of product function. And is that that i dont know how to do...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example. You can use the `*` operator to unpack a variable number of argument from a list and give it to `itertools.product()`:

```
import itertools

size1 = (3,5,6)
size2 = (2,2,2)
N = len(size1)
coords = []
for i in range(N):
    delta = size1[i]-size2[i]
    coords.append(list(range(delta)))
    
print(coords)
it = itertools.product(*coords)
arr = np.array(list(it))
print(arr)
```

**Output**:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 0 2]
 [0 0 3]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 1]
 [0 1 2]
 [0 1 3]
 [0 2 0]
 [0 2 1]
 [0 2 2]
 [0 2 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Im going to post the solution I obtained:

```
import numpy as np 
from itertools import product
A=np.ones((2,3,2))
B=np.zeros((3,4,4))
coords=[]
for i in range(len(B.shape)):
    delta = B.shape[i]-A.shape[i]+1
    coords.append(list(range(delta)))
print(coords)
for start_idx in product(*coords):
    idx=tuple(slice(start_idx[i], start_idx[i]+A.shape[i]) for i in range(len(A.shape)))
    m=np.zeros(B.shape)
    m.__setitem__(tuple(idx), A)  
    print(m)
```

ps: Indexing the nd arrays was very tricky